# removing m_ prefix from variable names

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, macros

Initially we planned to have old convention of having m_ prefix for class variables. But now requirement has come to replace all the m_VaribaleName to this.variableName, i.e. remove the m_ and make the first character after m_ lowercase.

I can search and replace m_ with this. but this doesn't rename the variable's first character to lowercase. After search and replace if I use re-factoring tool to rename VariableName to variableName this also renames the property already exists with VariableName.

I am wondering is there any regex, tool, macro to make this task automated.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper will highlight all such errors in a solution, and fix them individually, but I don't think it can fix all of them with a single command. Still, it's easy enough to navigate between errors that it finds.

Comment: Resharper changes m_VariableName to _mVariableName

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in emacs.

Open your file (`C-x C-f`) and do `M-x replace-regexp`.
Let's say the name of the variable is `Variable`.

Your regexp query would replace `\(V\)ariable` for `\,(downcase \1)ariable`.

The `\,` tells emacs the following statement is a lisp expression.

Additionally, if you wanted to replace the m_ at the same time you could do replace `m_\(V\)ariable` for `\,(downcase \1)ariable`.

This **will** take care of all instances in a file at the same time and emacs does remember your last replace-regexp query so you do not have to retype it for multiple files. Furthermore, there is a way using DIRED mode to do the replace-regexp on multiple files at the same time.

Open up a directory on DIRED mode (`C-x C-f DIR_NAME`), mark the files you want by going over them (you can navigate using `n` and `p`) by pressing `m`. Once the files you want to process are marked press `Q` (capital-case). You will get the same regexp prompt as if you did a single file, enter the regexp, `RET`, the replacement, and `RET`. It will open up each file at a time, press `!` for every file to replace all reg-exps in that file.

After that, you still have to save the files. Which you can do with `C-s` and then `!`.